# Authentication Through Telegram Bot

Tags: laravel, authentication, telegram, telegram-bot

I just wanted users of my Laravel web app to interact with their content through Telegram bot. Fore example, I want a website user to view and manage his profile information, content he created on the website and so on, on Telegram using custom keyboard provided in Telegram bots. My problem is, I want the user to login first and I don't know how to implement it. I hope there is a way to do it and I appreciate your help.

Comment: please explain more, you can use middleware

Comment: I have a Laravel web app and I have a Telegram bot connected to it. I want a user to login to the website on the Telegram bot and see his website content on Telegram

Comment: I think you can't do this because you need to access the local storage and the cookies of the browser